# Update database stored procedures while upgrading a module - Odoo

Tags: postgresql, odoo

There is an option in the menifest file to call method during module installation. We can mention `pre_init` and `post_init`.

I would like to call one method while upgrading the module as similar to pre_init. because after module gets installed pre_init will not be called.

Any suggestion for this ?

Why I need this ...

I have a stored procedure to generate report data quickly which uses postgresql stored procedure, now when there is a slight change in the procedure I would like to update it thourh the module upgrade process.

There should be some option available to call method during **upgrade module** as like `pre_init` and `post_init`.

I tried following methods to do this.

```
# Added following code in XML file
<function model="sale.order" name="action_custom_method"/>

@api.model
def action_custom_method(self):
    # stored procedure code
    return True
```

But this is not working for me, I am Using odoo 14.

Answer (score 0):

in Odoo 14 it became `pre_init_hook` & `post_init_hook`. which would be set in the `__manifest__.py`

```py
{
    'pre_init_hook': pre_init_hook_method,
    'post_init_hook': post_init_hook_method,
}
```

you also add the method definition in `__init__.py`

```py
def pre_init_hook_method(cr):
    env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {}) # to get env

def post_init_hook_method(cr, registry):
    env = api.Environment(cr, SUPERUSER_ID, {}) # to get env
```

you may also use the `migrations` folder & module versioning like what is mentioned there [Data Migration](https://odoo-development.readthedocs.io/en/latest/maintenance/data-migration.html)

so in your module folder you would have a `migration` folder. as the following structure:

```
<moduledir>
`-- migrations
        |-- 1.0
        |   |-- pre-update_table_x.py
        |   |-- pre-update_table_y.py
        |   |-- post-create_plop_records.py
        |   |-- end-cleanup.py
        |   `-- README.txt                      # not processed
        |-- 12.0.1.1                            # processed only on a 12.0 server
        |   |-- pre-delete_table_z.py
        |   `-- post-clean-data.py
        |-- 0.0.0
        |   `-- end-invariants.py               # processed on all version update
```

so if your module defined with version like `12.0.1.1` before. you could increment a number to be like `12.0.1.2` in `__manifest__.py`. later on in your `migration` folder you add a new folder `12.0.1.2`. where you could add `pre-` or `post-` python files. which would include you stored procedure definition. please also note that folder `0.0.0` will always run. if that didn't work it could be something else is wrong.
don't hesitate to let us know if you face any problems.

Comment: it won't help when we upgrade module, it works only when module is installing or just after installation. But won't working when we upgrade module.

Comment: if you don't mind could you give us more details about what are you try to do. what the method you need to be called do exactly??

Comment: We used stored procedure to generate data for report, so when there is slight change in stored procedure there is no such way to do it without uninstall and install again. That's why I would like to update stored procedure while upgrading modules.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got the solution.

We created one `.sql` file and into that file we added all our stored procedures and other database objects.

We added that sql file in the `__manifest__.py`

```
'data': [            
            'db_function/get_product_sales_history_data.sql',
            'db_function/update_product_sales_history.sql',
        ],
```

It will execute these sql files at the time of module installation as well as module upgrade time.